# Autenticar un usuario con hash y helper

Tags: c#, visual-studio

tengo el siguiente código para autenticar a un usuario.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
  public virtual async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ActionResult> Index1(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            string sql = @"SELECT COUNT(*)
                      FROM USURAIO
                      WHERE USUARIO_ACCESO = @usuario AND PASSWORD = @password";


    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["default"].ToString()))
            {
                conn.Open();

                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", model.Username);

                string hash = Helper.EncodePassword(string.Concat(model.Username, model.Password));
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", hash);

                int count = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());

                if (count == 0)
                    return Json(new { success = false, message = false }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                else
                   return Json(new { success = true, message = true, url = Url.Action("Index", "Home") }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

            }
        }
```

pero me sale un error en el `helper` dice que no existe en el contexto actual, tengo entendido que con un `using` debería funcionar, pero no se cual es ni como solucionarlo. 
Les agradezco si me pueden ayudar

[image: Este es el error que les comento.]

Comment: El helper se encuentra en otro proyecto o dll?

Comment: Entiendo que haces referencia a [este post](https://ltuttini.blogspot.com/2010/05/login-usando-password-con-hash.html) de nuestro compañero @LeandroTuttini
. Si te fijas en dicha publicación, verás el código fuente de la clase `Helper`

Comment: ahhhh si no habia visto eso, gracias.

Comment: Un pequeño tip: en **Visual Studio** posiciona el cursor sobre la línea que te da el error, presiona la combinación de teclas `Ctrl` + `.` (punto) y te dará opciones para arreglar el error. En este caso, te debería dar la línea `using` que necesitas.

Comment: gracias, la solucion era que me faltaba la clase que dice @Pikoh